# Is it possible to execute code after Exit Sub In vb6?

Tags: vb6, exit

Is there anyway to execute code after exit sub? In the following code:

```
If Dir("C:\My Folder\myfile.dll") <> "" Then
   Exit Sub
End If

'Somecodehere etc
```

I tried to put the exit sub at the end of my whole code, but if the dll is detected, then exit sub doesn't work.

Comment: Just excute your code (or call required function or whatever) before Exit Sub?

Comment: `Exit Sub` literally means "ignore everything that comes after this line in the current sub-procedure". Can you tell us what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Brian , Thats exactly what i did, i executed my whole code before exit sub, but it doesn't work. When i say it doesn't work, i mean the whole code is executed, but the code where is "If Dir etc doesn't exit.
 
41686d6564 stands w. PalestineI'm trying to experiment with security purposes, and then present it as a project

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You could put a breakpoint on the `Exit Sub` line (or the `if`) and then run your code. When the breakpoint is hit you can then step line by line and see what happens.

Comment: Given your code, if `Dir("C:\My Folder\myfile.dll")` returns `""`, then the `Somecodehere` will run. There is no problem with that.

Comment: Not totally clear to me, but it sounds like you're saying that the `Exit Sub` was executed, and then the `'Somecodehere etc` was also executed?  If that's your statement/question, then no, not possible - you aren't understanding what's executing and what the root problem is, in which case StayOnTarget's suggestion to debug and singlestep your code is an excellent next step for you to take and investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to execute code after Exit Sub in VB6. Exit Sub means that the execution of the current Sub procedure stops at that point and returns to the calling code.

If you want to execute some code after checking for the dll file, you can use an If-Else statement instead of Exit Sub. For example:

```
If Dir(“C:\My Folder\myfile.dll”) <> “” Then 
    'Some code here if dll is detected 
Else 
    'Some code here if dll is not detected 
End If
```

Comment: If `Exit Sub` is being executed conditionally, such as inside of an `If`, then there absolutely can be code after that `If` (and by extension, that `Exit Sub`), which will be executed if the `If` is not entered. There is no need to introduce the `Else` for that purpose alone.

Comment: @GSerg You are right